# How to run Linux on a QEMU ARM Versatile machine?

Tags: linux, arm, qemu

I'm trying to run linux on qemu, especially the versatile version.

I downloaded qemu and linux from github.
(qemu : https://github.com/qemu/qemu.git, linux : https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git)

I think these two repositorys are the main project of them.

Anyway, I compiled linux with 2 steps.

1. make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig
2. make all ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-

Also compiled qemu with 3 steps.

1. ./configure
2. make
3. sudo make install

And I ran it with this command:

```
../qemu/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel ./arch/arm/boot/zImage
```

And a window popped up with just a black screen. What should I do after that?

Comment: I would ask this question on [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255408/running-chown-in-bash-script-produces-errors) since it doesn't really have anything to do with programming or software related to programming.

Comment: Wow thank you. i didn't know about the Unix and Linux before you told me. i think it's better for asking there instead.

Comment: Yes i will leave a proper answer later. sorry for my title

Comment: @RadLexus Sorry for edit the answer late. But i did it. If you need any more detailed or question, please let me know i will add more for you.

Comment: @RadLexus Thank you for your advice. I posted my answer on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded qemu and linux from github.
(qemu : https://github.com/qemu/qemu.git, 
linux : https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git)

I think these two repositorys are the main project of them.

Anyway, I compiled linux with 2 steps.

1. make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig
2. make all ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-

Also compiled qemu with 3 steps.

1. ./configure
2. make
3. sudo make install

To mount the root filesystem, I downloaded busybox. (I'm not sure, but this busybox is the mostly used filesystem to develper when they want to make simple enviroment)

I downloaded busybox and i followed some steps.

1. wget http://www.busybox.net/downloads/busybox-1.24.1.tar.bz2
2. tar -xvf busybox-1.24.1.tar.bz2
3. cd busybox-1.24.1/
4. make defconfig
5. make menuconfig (to make binary as static not shared)
6. make -j8
7. make install
8. cd _install
9. find . | cpio -o --format=newc > ../rootfs.img
10. cd ..
11. gzip -c rootfs.img > rootfs.img.gz

So, my final command is

```
../qemu/arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel ./arch/arm/boot/zImage -nographic -dtb arch/arm/boot/dts/versatile-pb.dtb -initrd ../rootfs.img.gz -append "root=/dev/ram0 initrd=/bin/sh"
```

I ran linux on qemu especially versatile version

here is my current status of file with 'ls' command

To run the upper command, the linux, qemu and filesystem images should be located like this (except other projects like FreeRTOS it's only for my situation)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Buildroot**

```
git clone https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot
cd buildroot
git checkout 2017.02
make qemu_arm_versatile_defconfig
make BR2_JLEVEL="$(($(nproc) - 2))"
# From: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/board/qemu/arm-versatile/readme.txt
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel output/images/zImage -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200" -serial stdio -net user -net nic,model=smc91c111
```

Welcome to automation Nirvana.